# Never seen a 17 by 25 grid before? Well now you have

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

SNY.SMARTIE.ISDROPPEDONTO.AFRICTIONLESS.PLANE.WITH.NEGLIGIBLE.FRICTION..UPUPUPUP

[image]

Hint:

> Look at remaining letters for a secret!

> This puzzle is a little visual... just a little though, I believe color-blinds can do it as well.

Comment: Sorry, there is a missing digit. Maybe you can think of it as intentional, since I quite like how it is neatly rectangular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

> 1) The num pad cipher where 1 is NW, 2 is N and, 3 is NE, 4 is E etc.

> and then 2) converting the numbers underneath in the black tiles with the addition of 6 as digit no.8 (reading left to right) and 8 as digit no.26 into those directions.

> and then 3) Starting from the grey square on the top left corner of the grid

> And then 4) following the directions starting from 9 (SE) reading left to right.

> and then 5) by using a direction we keep on collecting all the letters, putting them in order of ‘contact’ to make a word until we hit a highlighted bold square where we then add a space to the message and then use the next direction

We get:

> [image]

And the message which is:

> OH MY GOD WHY IS THIS SO ICY? I THINK I AM FALLING WHY IS IT SO ICY? I HOPE THAT I CAN STILL BACK UP TO LET ME STAND UP. WHY DO THOSE PHYSICISTS ALL LIKE TO ASSUME NO FRICTION? I AM SO SO SO HORN MAD! A AA AARGH! WAIT.

This leaves behind with the untouched letters and full stops:

> SNY.SMARTIE.ISDROPPEDONTO.AFRICTIONLESS.PLANE.WITH.NEGLIGIBLE.FRICTION..UPUPUPUP